# Database structure for large word-word co-occurrence frequencies with metadata

Tags: sql, nlp, amazon-dynamodb, graph-databases

I would like to store the frequencies with which words co-occur with each other over a variety of contexts in a large (> 1 Billion tokens) text corpus. I need to store the word pair, the type of co-occurrence (e.g. word1 in the same sentence as word2, word1 in the same paragraph as word2), and some metadata about the text in which the co-occurrence was found, (e.g. year, author, publisher). So a single row might look like:

```
word1     word2   count decade publisher author context_type
-------------------------------------------------------------
nuclear   danger   22    1980s    NYT      n/a      paragraph
```

The frequencies will be sparse and Poisson distributed. I would then like to be able to query the data by date ranges, or groups of authors (for example), aggregating the counts of the results.

I have little experience with databases and am not sure what to use. Do I need related SQL tables (e.g. with the book metadata in one table and word data in another), or a simple flat NoSql solution? The vocabulary is about 50,000 words, so the if every word-word co-occurrence was observed there would be 2.5 billion rows even without the metadata (I think). But probably most of them won't be observed. This makes me think maybe a graph database is a possible solution. Is there a good cloud solution on AWS or google maybe?

Comment: You can probably do this pretty easily using a relational database.  You would have a few tens of millions of rows (I'm guessing) and with the right structure, it would be easy to query.  However, Stack Overflow is not the place for software recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Bigtable or another NoSQL system could be a reasonable choice for this type of query since it sounds like a sparse dataset option, but as the previous posted noted, this question is more suited for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/.